# Excessive Disk Writes on Azure Blobs with WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

We recently transitioned from an Azure classic storage account to Azure GPv2 storage as it appeared to be cheaper from some calculations we did with the Azure calculator.

Here's a run down of the billing for a days worth of usage on the GPv2 storage account. Our current storage cost is now even higher than an S1 SQL Server instance at roughly .84 per day!

[image: Azure Billing]

We started digging into the disk usage as this appears to be the biggest part of the billing. The entry for "Hot Block Blob Write Operations" at 6,200 writes for one day appeared to be the most impactful, so we reviewed the blob storage logs for writes under $logs. We saw a lot of heartbeat calls and singleton locks for our webjobs. We only have a small number of webjobs (like 6-8) and some use TimerTriggers (which would explain the locks every 30s). None of these calls are from blob writes from our app, only from behind the scenes webjob actions.

[image: Azure Storage Disk Usage]

So my question is, has anyone experienced this kind of excessive usage? It seems that the webjobs are excessively chatty to the point that they will result in almost $30 per month in charges alone. We really love using webjobs, but I can only imagine how much more expensive it will be with even more webjobs. Is it possible to have the webjobs log to table storage or some cheaper mechanism? Are we seeing a double whammy from the webjob activity AND the $logs that are logging the webjob activity? We have all diagnostics disabled on the App Service and the blob storage, but it appears the $logs folder continues logging regardless.

Comment: Given the cost-model differences, can you use a v1 storage account for things like your webjob logs, and v2 elsewhere?

Comment: Hey David! I appreciate your response. Yes, this is something we had considered if there wasn't any other alternative. Hopefully the webjobs sdk folks might see this and chime in or take this into consideration for future releases.